# YQL + PHP : how to make a facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, yql, opensocial

I was reading some stuff about the YQL api that Yahoo! has provided, I am not sure, but it appears to be a collection of lots of third party api into one common language, right?

what I don't get is how to make the facebook login through it so I can get the user profile data...

My project is to add a facebook(and other social networks) form login, because the website won't have his own login, people will have to use a social network to link in. Then I thought the YQL would help me out with this task so I wouldn't have to develop lots of functions to each one of the networks.

Reading this http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#sdk_yql, I understood how to make a Yahoo login so I can access some private data, but couldn't find how I could do it with facebook and others

So my question... Can YQL help me with this? Can you give me a simple example of a facebook session using it within PHP? Are there alternatives to aid me in this task?

thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: Take a look http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt that YQL has an API that gives a free hand with facebook login. You have to consider how a login works. You send POST data to a web server containing client-side password hashes and encryptions, as well as other kinds of identification. YQL has no way to "standardize" logins - it would have to make a new API for every popular web site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , using YQL you will be able to do this task .. you can look at this demo http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/05/showing-facebook-twitter-rss-stats-jquery-yql/demo.html. Also if you are going to only use Facebook authentication , then there is no need for YQL you can do it using http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: that is a demo for counters, not logins. With that, developers are able to get data from social networks with users that they know of, now my point is with logins and  stuff, but thanks anyway